# How to change the size of cell of Gridview in JavaFx

Tags: gridview, javafx, controlsfx

I start a project using gridview in controlsFx. The size of cell of gridview is so small that I want to change it. However, when I call cellProperty.setXXX() or setCellXXX(XXX means Height or Width ),the size of cell does change, when it refer to displaying, it remain the size. How can I do it?
My code about cell and layout follow.

```
public class AlbumCell extends GridCell<Album> {


ImageView img_cover;
Label ll_albumName;

@Override
protected void updateItem(Album item, boolean empty) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    // create the view;
    VBox box = new VBox();
    img_cover = new ImageView();
    ll_albumName = new Label();
    if (empty) {
        img_cover.setImage(new Image("Pic/bg.jpeg"));
        ll_albumName.setText("相册名");
    } else {
        img_cover = new ImageView(item.getCoverUrl());
        ll_albumName.setText(item.getAlbumName());
    }
    //如何改变单元格的大小?
    box.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    img_cover.setFitHeight(70);
    img_cover.setFitWidth(70);
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    box.getChildren().addAll(img_cover,ll_albumName);
    setGraphic(box);

}
```

}

```
<StackPane   GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="3"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="5">
        <children>

            <GridView fx:id="albumsList" 

            />

        </children>
    </StackPane>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use Gluon Scenebuilder. http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Comment: What do you mean to mention that? I think this has nothing to do with UI design.

Comment: Scenebuilder is another way of setting the values he needs to set.

Comment: See if cellProperty has something like cellProperty.setMinWidth or cellProperty.setMinHeight and set those. Also try look for cellProperty.setPreferedHeight and cellProperty.setPreferedWidth.

Comment: I think I know what's you mean. But Scene Builder has no gridview.

Comment: It still doesn't work . Although I change the size of cell in fxml, when it refer to display, it remains.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is fairly old:
You can use `GridView.cellWidthProperty()` and `GridView.cellHeightProperty()` to change the size of the cells inside your [GridView](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.0.3/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html).